# Is there evidence of the miracles of Tulsidas?

Tags: rama, bhakti

Several miracles are attributed to the great medieval poet and philosopher Tulsidas, among them reviving the dead, and one of the ones that most caught my attention, his arrest by Emperor Akbar, and who himself was released by an army of angry monkeys, as it is said in: "It is said he recited the Hanuman Chalisa hundreds of times. Upon doing so, a large hoard of uncontrollable monkeys laid siege on the jail in which Tulsidas was imprisoned. Akbar’s forces failed to control the monkeys who had created havoc in the prison as well as in the royal palace. Akbar’s advisors informed him that this was because of capturing the great Brahmin, Tulsidas and his bhakti towards Lord Hanuman". Is there any evidence at the time to prove whether this event actually occurred? Did Akbar really arrest him, and that he was released by monkeys? Undoubtedly, an event of such magnitude must be documented by the sources at the time.

Comment: I think it would be more suitable on History SE ..

Answer (score -1):

सीतानाथ समारम्भां रामानन्दार्य मध्यमाम्।
अस्मदाचार्य पर्यन्तां वन्दे श्रीगुरू परम्पराम् ।।

भक्तमाल सुमेरू श्रीमद् गोस्वामी तुलसीदास जी महाराज के चरणों में कोटि-कोटि नमन;
तुलसीदास जी महाराज हिंदू समाज की एकता के प्राण कहे गए हैं, जिन्होंने अपने कालजई काव्य से संपूर्ण हिंदू समाज को एक सूत्र में बांध दिया था। मैंने स्वयं कुछ हिंदू संगठनों के अधिकारियों से बात करी थी और उनसे पूछा था कि आपके अनुसार हिंदू धर्म को अभी तक किस चीज ने बचा के रखा है तो एक बात मैं बहुत गर्व से कह सकता हूं कि सभी का मत एक ही था हनुमान चालीसा और सुंदरकांड ने। अगर तुलसीदास जी ना होते तो हिंदू समाज इतना बिखर चुका होता और इसाई मिशनरी इतने पीछे पड़ जाते हिंदुओं के कि इनको इसाई बने बिना राहत नहीं होती। ऐसे महापुरुष को तो मेरा शत-शत नमन है।

अब आते हैं मुख्य बात पर कि तुलसीदास सरकार का वर्णन किस ग्रंथ में मिलता है और उनके द्वारा रचित रामायण का महात्म्य क्या है?

सर्वप्रथम तो मैं क्षमा चाहूंगा कि मुझे उनके होने के प्रमाण देने पड़ रहे हैं लेकिन रीत यही रही है कि जो दिखता है लोग उसी पर विश्वास करते हैं इसी कड़ी में मेरा भी यही प्रयास है कि मैं विभिन्न शास्त्रों के माध्यम से तुलसीदास जी और उनके द्वारा रचित वेदसार ग्रंथों का महात्म्य बता सकूं !!

प्रारंभ:~

वाल्मीकिस्तुलसीदासः कलौ देवि भविष्यति ।
रामचन्द्रकथामेतां भाषाबद्धां करिष्यति ॥

(भविष्य पुराण प्रतिसर्ग ४.२०)

भविष्योत्तर पुराणमें संपूर्ण श्रीरामकथा कहकर भगवान् भूतभावन शङ्करजी, भगवती पार्वतीजीसे कहते हैं – “हे पार्वतीजी! महर्षि वाल्मीकि ही कलियुगमें तुलसीदास बनेंगे और इस रामकथाको भाषाबद्ध करेंगे अर्थात् अवधी भाषामें निबद्ध करेंगे।”

और इसी बात का समर्थन अन्य शास्त्र भी करते हैं जिनके प्रमाण निम्न है:~

वासिष्ठ संहितायाम् (उपासना त्रय सिद्धांत से उद्दित, पृष्ठ 55)

वाल्मीकितुलसीदासः कलौ देवि भविष्यति ।
रामचन्द्रकथां साध्वीं भाषारूपां करिष्यति ॥

शिव संहितायाम् (गीता प्रेस गोरखपुर वेद कथा अंक से उद्दित पृष्ठ 285)

वाल्मीकिस्तुलसीदासः कलौ देवि भविष्यति ।
रामचन्द्रकथां साध्वी भाषारूपां करिष्यति ॥

ब्रह्म संहितायाम् (उपासना त्रयसिद्धांत से उद्दित, पृष्ठ 55)

वाल्मीकिस्तुलसीदासः कलौ देवि भविष्यति ।
रामचन्द्रकथां साध्वी भाषारूपां करिष्यति ॥

उपरोक्त तीनों श्लोकों के अर्थ वही हैं जो भविष्य पुराण के श्लोक का है।

भक्तमाल के रचयिता श्री वैष्णव आचार्य श्रीमद गोस्वामी नाभादास जी महाराज ने भी अपने ग्रंथ में तुलसीदास जी को लेकर यही लिखा है, (सन्‌ 1585)

"कलि कुटिल जीव निस्तार हित वाल्मीक तुलसी भयो"

(इति भक्तमाल, 129 छप्पयै, पृष्ठ 131, मलूक पीठ संस्करण)

कलयुग के जीव को भवसागर से पार लगाने के लिए वाल्मीकि जी ने तुलसीदास जी के रूप में अवतार लिया।

एक बात मैं यहां साझा करना चाहूंगा कि जिन लोगों को इतना भी ज्ञान नहीं होता कि संस्कृत की वर्णमाला में कितने वर्ण आते हैं उनको भी श्लोक संस्कृत में ही चाहिए होते हैं यह बहुत बड़ी विडंबना है हमारे समाज में, भले ही स्वयं को इतना भी ज्ञान ना हो कि स्वर व्यंजन किसे कहते हैं लेकिन श्लोक संस्कृत में होने चाहिए भले ही संस्कृत में अपशब्द ही क्यों ना दी हो। एक बात हम सब को यह समझ नहीं पड़ेगी कि शास्त्रों की दो भाषाएं हैं एक संस्कृत और एक अवधि। जब इस्लामिक आक्रांता ओं ने हमारे ऊपर आक्रमण किया तो संस्कृत का पठन-पाठन उत्तर भारत में बहुत नीचे पर चला गया, जिसके कारण लोग गुरुकुल नहीं जा पा रहे थे लेकिन शास्त्रों की रचना तो आवश्यक थी, इसीलिए उस समय के बड़े-बड़े संतो ने अपनी रचनाएं साधारण सी दिखने वाली अवधी भाषा में करी, लेकिन इसका तात्पर्य आप यह ना लगाएं की अवधि भाषा में लिखा हुआ ग्रंथ है तो इसकी प्रमाणिकता कोई कम होगी। मैं अपने जीवन में लगभग 4 संस्कृत के प्राध्यापकों से मिला हूं, और एक से तो मैं वाराणसी में मिला था जिनके घर में गया था कुछ प्रश्नों के उत्तर जानने के लिए।
तो उन्होंने कहा यह प्रश्न तो बहुत सरल है इसका उत्तर तो मानस में दिया हुआ है बैठिए मैं मानस लाता हूं, लगभग 15 कदम की दूरी पर उनका बुक्शेल्फ था, उन्होंने अपने जेब से रुमाल निकाली अपने सर पर बिछाई फिर मानस के ग्रंथ को उठाया अपने सर पर रखा और मेरे पास लाए और रुमाल बिछा कर फिर उसके ऊपर मानस को रखा।
श्रीमद रामचरितमानस को लेकर इतना प्रेम मैंने पहली बार देखा था, मेरे से रहा नहीं गया मैं उनसे पूछ पड़ा कि आप तो संस्कृत के विद्वान हैं आप मुझे लगा कि आप केवल संस्कृत के श्लोकों के पीछे जाते होंगे तो उन्होंने हंसकर एक ही बात कही की जो बात मानस में है वो सब एक जगह है जो किसी भी शास्त्र में एक जगह नहीं है क्योंकि यह मानस एकमात्र ऐसा ग्रंथ है जो ब्रह्म सूत्र का भी भाष्य है, गीता का भी संपूर्ण भाष्य है और यदि कोई सनातन तत्व को जानने का इच्छुक है तो उसकी जिज्ञासा का भी यह संपूर्ण भाष्य है।

अवधी एक शास्त्र सम्मत भाषा है जिसमें सनातन धर्म के कई शास्त्र लिखे गए हैं इसीलिए इस भाषा की प्रमाणिकता को लेकर कोई संदेह करना दूसरों के सामने अपनी मूर्खता सिद्ध करने के बराबर होगा।

अब मैं श्रीमद् गोस्वामी तुलसीदास जी महाराज और उनकी रामायण के प्रमाण बृहद ब्रम्ह रामायण से उद्धत कर रहा हूं; (इसके कुछ श्लोक गीता प्रेस गोरखपुर के वेद कथा अंक पृष्ठ 285 पर उपलब्ध हैं)

सर्वलोकोपकाराय प्रेरितो हरिणामुदा।
वाल्मीकिस्तुलसोस्दासस्तद् रूपेण भविष्यति।।

(श्री बृहद् ब्रह्म रामायण- प्र० १ श्लो०७८)

अर्थ-सभी लोगों के उपकार के हेतु श्रीहरि की इच्छा से श्री बाल्मीकि महर्षि ही श्री तुलसीदास जी के रूप में प्रगट होंगे।

वही से दूसरा प्रमाण~

भाषा काव्यं मानसाख्यं रामायरणमनुत्तमम् ।

करिष्यति जनानां यत्कलौ शीघ्र फलप्रदः ॥

(श्री बृहद ब्रह्म रा० प्र० १ श्लो० ७९)

अर्थ- श्री गोस्वामी जी सर्वोत्तम भाषा काव्य श्रीमानस रामायण नाम से प्रसिद्ध करेंगे जो कलियुग में सभी जनों को शीघ्र फल देने वाला होगा।

अब उसी बृहद ब्रम्ह रामायण में से श्रीमद् रामचरितमानस महातम में का वर्णन किया जा रहा है:~

श्रीभरद्वाज उवाच श्रीयाज्ञवल्क्य के प्रति~
१)
घोरे कलियुगे ब्रह्मन् जनानां पाप कर्मणाम् ।
मनः शुद्धि विहीनानां निष्कृतिश्च कथं भवेत् ॥

अर्थ:~ श्रीभरद्वाज जी ने कहा कि 'हे ब्रह्मन् ! घोर कलियुग के पाप कर्म में रत, मन के शुद्धि से रहित मनुष्यों का उद्धार किस प्रकार होगा।

२)
नत्यं दाशरथेर्घामायोध्याख्यां वर्णितं त्वया । वाल्मीकिं नारदः प्राह ब्रह्मलोकं गमिष्यति ॥

अर्थ:~श्रीदशरथ नन्दन श्रीरामजी का नित्यधाम श्रीअयोध्याजी है, यह आपने वर्णन किया और श्रीवाल्मीकि जी से नारदजी ने कहा कि श्रीरामजी हजारो वर्ष राज्य करके अपने नित्य धाम ब्रह्मलोक का जायेंगे।

३)
अत्र जाता मदीयान्तःकरणे शंका गरीयसी । तन्निवर्तयितुं शक्तो राम तत्त्व विदाम्बरः ।।

अर्थ:~यहाँ मेरे मन में भारी शंका उत्पन्न हुई हैं, उसको निवारा करने के लिये श्रीरामतत्त्व को जानने वालों में आप ही सब श्रेष्ठ हैं।

४)
यथा तुष्यति देवेशो देव देवो जगद् गुरुः ।
अतो वदस्व धर्मज्ञ सर्व धर्म भृताम्वर ॥

अर्थ:~और हे धर्म को जानने वाले तथा सभी धर्म धारणा करने वालों में श्रेष्ठ ! आप यह भी कहिये कि किस प्रकार से जगद्गुरु देवों के देव सर्व देवेश श्रीरामजी प्रसन्न होंगे !

श्रीयाज्ञवल्क्य उवाच~
५)
वाल्मीकिस्तुलसीदासो भविष्यति कलौ युगे ।
शिवेनात्र कृतो ग्रन्थः पार्वतीं प्रतिबोधितम् ॥

अर्थ:~श्रीयाज्ञवल्क्यजी ने कहा कि-कलियुग में श्रीवाल्मीकि जी गोस्वामी तुलसीदासजी के रूप से अवतार लेंगे, ये श्रीगोस्वामी तुलसीदासजी, शिवजी ने पार्वती को जो ज्ञान कराने के लिये जो ग्रन्थ बनाया है उस श्रीरामचरित मानस को।

६)
राम भक्ति प्रवाहार्थं भाषा काव्यं करिष्यति।
रामायणं मानसाख्यं तत्ते शंकां निवारयेत् ॥

अर्थ:~उसी ग्रन्थ के माध्यम से श्रीराम भक्ति के रस को प्रवाहित कराने के लिये अर्थात् बढ़ाने के किये श्रीमानस रामायण ग्रन्थ का भाषा काव्य करेंगे, वही ग्रन्थ आपके शंका का निवारण करेगा।

७)
करिष्यति स रामस्य नखोत्सव मनोहरम् ।
विरागदीपनी नामा बरवा च सुमंगलम् ॥
पार्वती जानकी नाम्ना रामाज्ञा भक्ति वर्धिनी ।

अर्थ:~और यही श्रीगोस्वामीजी "रामलला नहँछु" नाम का मनोहर ग्रन्थ करेंगे तथा वैराग्यसंदीपनी", "बरबै रामायण", "पावती मंगल" एवं "श्रीजानकी मंगल" और श्रीरामाज्ञा प्रश्न ये भक्ति को बढ़ाने वाले ग्रन्थ को बनायेंगे।

८)
दोहावलीं कवित्ताख्यां रामगीत कथानकम् । कृष्णगीतं मानसं च पत्रिं विनय संज्ञकाम् ॥

अर्थ:~और दोहावली, कवितावली, श्रीरामगीतावली और श्रीकृष्ण गीतावली तथा मानस रामायण एवं विनय पत्रिका नामक ग्रंथ बनावेंगे।

९)
सुखदं सर्व जावानां संसार तिमिरापहम । रामधाम प्रदं भव्यं मंगलानां सुमंगलम ॥

अर्थ:~ये सब काव्य सभी जीवों को सुख देने वाले हैं तथा संसार के अन्धकार अर्थात् अज्ञान को नाश करने वाले एवं श्रीरामजी के धाम को देने वाले, अति सुन्दर मंगलों को भी मंगल प्रदाता हैं।

१०)
समस्त मंत्र शास्त्रस्य यंत्र मंत्रं प्रविस्तरम् ।
स्वापयामास गोस्वामी पत्री विनय मध्यतः॥

अर्थ:~ सभी मंत्र शास्त्र के यंत्र मंत्रों को विस्तार से श्रीगोस्वामी ने विनय पत्रिका में स्थापित किया है।

११)
सर्व मन्त्र मयं काव्यं साधकानां सुसिद्धिदम् ।
सत्यं सत्यं मुनि श्रेष्ठ सद्यः सिद्धि प्रदं कलौः।।

अर्थ:~अत एव श्रीगोस्वामीजी के सभी काव्य मन्त्रमय हैं और साधकों को कलियुग में शीघ्र सुन्दर सिद्धि को देने वाले हैं, हे मुनिश्रेष्ठ ! यह मैं तुमसे सस्य-सत्य कहता है।

१२)
दशोनदश साहस्री श्रीमद्रामायणं मुने ।
संख्यां विरहितं चान्यत्सर्वं काव्य करिष्यति ॥

अर्थ:~हे मुने ! दश कम दश हजार अर्थात् नौ हजार नौ सौ नब्बे श्रीमद्रामायणजी की संख्या हैं परन्तु और सब काव्य नियम रहित श्रीगोस्वामीजी करेंगे।

१३)
यद्यद् भाषा कृतं काव्यं राम चरित्र संयुतं ।
भाषा रामायणस्येव पठनाच्छ्रवणान्मुने ।।

अर्थ:~वो जो अन्य भाषा काव्य हैं वे सभी श्रीरामजी के चरित्र संयुक्त हैं परन्तु भाषा रामायण अर्थात श्रीराम चरित मानस के पठन तथा श्रवण से हे मुने।

१४)
सद्यः पुनन्ति वै सर्वे चिरकालं तथान्यतः।
धमार्थ काम मोक्षाणां साधनं च द्विजोत्तम ।।

अर्थ:~समस्त प्राणी इससे तुरन्त पवित्र होते हैं इसकी अपेक्षा अन्य ग्रन्थों से बहुत काल में पवित्र होते हैं। और धर्म, अर्थ, काम और मोक्ष चारों फलों के प्राप्त करने का सबसे श्रेष्ठ यह साधन है।

१५)
श्रोतव्यं सदा भक्त्या रामायण रसामृतम् ।
नाना विधि निषेधाश्च गुरु शुक्रस्य मौढयता।।

अर्थ:~इसलिये हे द्विज श्रेष्ठ ! अमृत रस रूप श्रीमान मानस रामायणा को मदा सुनना चाहिये और नाना प्रकार के विधि निषेध तथा बृहस्पति और शुक्र के उदय अस्त का विचार,

१६)
स्पृशन्ति कदाचिद्वै सदा सर्वत्र सिद्धिदम् ।
ऊज्र्जे माघे सिते पक्षे चैत्रे च द्विजसत्तम ॥

अर्थ:~श्री रामायण के पाठ में कभी स्पर्श नहीं कर सकता क्योंकि यह सर्वत्र सब सिद्धि को देने वाला है। तो भी कार्तिक, माघ, चैत्र इन मासों के शुक्ल पक्ष में, हे द्विज सत्तम,

१७)
नवाह्ना खलु श्रोतव्यं रामायण कथामृतम् ।
अथवा माधवे विप्र मार्गशीर्षे च श्रावणे ।।

अर्थ:~श्रीरामायण कथामृत को नियम से नौ दिनों में समस्त सुनना चाहिये अथवा हे विप्र ! वैशाख, अगहन, श्रावण,

१८)
याश्विने फाल्गुने चैव शुक्ल पत्ते विशेषतः ।
वार्षिकेद्विशतं दद्यात् त्रिंशद् दद्याच्च मासिके।।

अर्थ:~तथा आश्विन फाल्गुन इन महीनों के शुक्ल पक्ष में नवाह रूप में विशेष करके श्रीरामायणजी को श्रवण करें, और वर्ष भर नित्य प्रति रामायण सुनने में वक्ता को दक्षिणा दें, और मास पारायण में अर्थात एक मास कथा करके श्रोता वक्त को दक्षिणा दें।

१९)
नवाह्ने च तथा विप्र दद्याच्च पंच विंशतिः ।
अन्यथा कुरुते यस्तु न तस्य फल भाग भवेत्।।

अर्थ:~ तथा नवाह्न में हे विप्र ! वक्ता को पच्चीस मुद्रा देना चाहिये ये हिसाब अन्य युगों के लिए हे कलियुग में तो मास भर श्रोता को १२० मुद्रा और नवाह श्रोता को १९० मुद्रा वक्ता को अर्पण करना चाहिए। नहीं तो श्रीरामायणजी के अपमान करने से श्रोता फल का भागी नहीं हो सकता है।

२०)
भवेन्निरय गामी च पश्चात् कुष्ठी भवेद्भुवम्।
अत्र ते कथयिष्यामि इतिहासं पुरातनम्।।

अर्थ:~अन्त में नरक गामी होता है पीछे निश्चय कोढ़ी होता है । यहाँ पर मैं एक तुम से पुराना
इतिहास कहूंगा,

२१)
जगन्नाथ पुरस्यासीद्राजा परम धार्मिकः ।
वैष्णवाराधनरतो भगवद्धर्म पालकः ॥

अर्थ:~भगवद्धर्म पालक वैष्णवो की सेवा में तत्पर धार्मिक श्रीजगन्नाथपुरी का एक राजा था।

२२)
कौतूहल वशात्तेन समाज सहितेन च।
श्रुतं रामायणं सर्वं मानसं तु मनोहरम् ॥

अर्थ:~जन समुदाय से श्रीमानस रामायणाजी की बढ़ाई सुनकर उस राजा ने कौतूहल वश समस्त मनोहर श्रीमानस रामायणजी को सुना।

२३)
कौतूहल वशात्तेन समाज सहितेन च।
श्रुतं रामायणं सर्वं मानसं तु मनोहरम् ॥

अर्थ:~ जन समुदाय से श्रीमानस रामायणाजी की बढ़ाई सुनकर उस राजा ने कोतूहल वंश समस्त मनोहर श्रीमानस रामायणजी को सुना |

२४)
वाचकं वैष्णवं शुद्धं रामभक्ति परायणम् !
भाषायां कोविदं मत्वा भाषा रामायणं तथा ।।

अर्थ:~कथा के बाँचने वाले शुद्ध श्रीरामभक्ति पर यथा को श्री वैष्णव को केवल संस्कृत भाषा का पति मान कर तथा श्रीरामायण जी को सामान्य भाषा में जानकर मनमें अपमान किया।

२५)
अवज्ञया द्वयश्वासौ दत्तवान् न च दक्षिणाम् ।
तेन पापेन शुद्धोऽपि वैष्णवोऽपि नृपोत्तमः ॥

अर्थ:~उन दोनों के अर्थात् श्रीमानस रामायण एवं वक्ता के अपमान की भावना से उस राजा ने कुछ भी दक्षिण नहीं दिया। उस पाप से वह राजा शुद्ध वैष्णव होने पर भी,

२६)
देहान्ते नरकं गत्वा शुशोच पापकृद्यथा ।
तं विलोक्य सक्रोधेन यमेनोक्तः स राजराट्।।

अर्थ:~देहान्त होने पर वह राजा नरक को गया और जैसे पाप करने वाला सोचता है वैसे सोचने लगा, उसको देखकर क्रोध से युक्त होकर यमराज बोले।

२७)
पापात्मायं महामानी मिथ्यालापी विमूढधीः ।
रामायणं वेद समं भाषां मत्वा कुबुद्धितः ॥

अर्थ:~ कि यह पापात्मा है और महा अभिमानी विमूढ़ बुद्धि वाला (बड़ामूर्ख) मिथ्या बोलने वाला है। इसने श्रीमान रामायण जी वेद के समान है उसको अपनी बुद्धि से सामान्य भाषा का मानकर,

२८)
अनाहत्य विमूढात्मा वाचकं वैष्णवं तथा ।
श्रुत्वा रामायणं सर्वं दक्षिणा नैव दत्तवान् ॥

अर्थ:~अपमान किया और बाँचने वाले श्रीवैष्णव का अनादर किया, समस्त रामायण सुनकर मी दक्षिणा नहीं दिया।

२९)
संतुष्टं शील सम्पन्नमाचार्यं प्राप्य भाग्यतः ।
मिष्ट मिष्टतरैर्वाक्यैः न प्रशादितवान् स्वयम् ॥

अर्थ:~ सन्तोषी तथा शील सम्पन्न आचार्य (वक्ता) भाग्य से मिलने पर भी उनको मीठे-मीठे वचनों से भी सन्तुष्ट नहीं किया।

३०)
ततोऽयं नरकं प्राप्तो विष्णु धर्मरतोऽपि च।
स्वधर्म भस्मसात्कृत्वा मत्समापमिहागतः ॥

अर्थ:~उसी कारण से विष्णु धर्म में तत्पर रहते हुए भी यह नरक को प्राप्त हुआ, श्रीरामायणजी के अपमान रूप पाप से अपने धर्म को भस्म (नाश) कर दिया और यहाँ नर्क में मेरे पास आया है।

~बृहद ब्रह्म रामायण में वर्णित श्रीमद् रामचरितमानस महातम संपूर्ण हुआ।

इसके साथ साथ श्री महाकाल संहिता में भी श्रीमद् रामचरितमानस के पाठ के फल का वर्णन मिलता है,

भव रोग हरी भक्तिः शक्ति यस्व शुभ प्रदा ।
ज्ञान वैराग्य सहितं कीलकं यस्य कीर्तिम् ।
तं मानसं राम रूपं रामायणमनुत्तमम् ।
प्रणमामि सदा भक्त्या शरणं च गतोस्म्यहं ॥
श्रीमदरामायणं दिव्यं मानसं भुक्ति मुक्तिदम् ।
यस्व श्रवण मात्रेण पापिनोऽपि दिवंगताः ॥

(इति महाकाल संहिता)

तुलसीदास जी महाराज से जुड़े हुए प्रमाण का‌ अंत नहीं है बस मैं प्रमाण डालते जाऊं और आप पढ़ते जाएं इसका अंत कभी नहीं होने वाला इसीलिए विस्तार भय से यही तक प्रमाण डाल रहा हूं।

यह सब थी प्रमाण की बातें अब तुलसीदास जी महाराज के जीवन से जुड़ी हुई कुछ महत्वपूर्ण घटनाएं जान लेते हैं;

लेकिन उससे पहले आपको एक बात समझ नहीं पड़ेगी कि तुलसीदास जी ने अपने मन से कोई भी बात नहीं लिख दी है श्रीरामचरितमानस में, उनके इस काव्य को;
"नानापुराणनिगमागम सम्मतं यद् रामायणे निगदितं क्वचिदन्यतोऽपि" कहा गया है,

यानी उनका यह काव्य वेद, पुराण, 6 दर्शन, आगम आदि सबसे सम्मत है।
इसीलिए महापुरुषों ने श्रीमद् रामचरितमानस को संपूर्ण वैदिक दर्शन का सार कहा है।

संवत् 1620 की माघ कृष्ण अमावस्या अर्थात् मौनी अमावस्याके परम पावन पर्वपर श्रीचित्रकूटके रामघाटपर बनी अपनी कुटियामें विराजमान मलयचन्दन उतारते हुए श्रीतुलसीदासजीके समक्ष श्रीरामलक्ष्मण दो बालकोंके रूपमें उपस्थित हुए और बोले – “ऐ बाबा! हमें भी तो चन्दन दो।” इन भुवनसुन्दर बालकोंको देखकर श्रीतुलसीदासजी महाराज ठगे-से रह गए और भगवान् श्रीरामजी अपने मस्तकपर चन्दनका तिलक लगाकर तुलसीदासजीके भी मस्तकपर मलयगिरि­चन्दनसे ऊर्ध्वपुण्ड्र करने लगे। तब श्रीहनुमान्‌जीने सोचा – “कहीं यह बाबा फिर न ठगा जाए और प्रभुको न पहचान पाए,” अतः अञ्जनानन्द­वर्धन प्रभु श्रीहनुमन्तलालजी सुन्दर तोतेका वेष बनाकर कुटीके निकटस्थ आमकी डालपर बैठकर प्रभुके परिचयसे ओत-प्रोत यह दोहा बोले –

चित्रकूट के घाट पर भइ सन्तन की भीर।
तुलसिदास चन्दन घिसें तिलक देत रघुबीर॥

आज भी सामान्य तोते चित्रकूटी दूध रोटी ही पहले बोलते हैं। अब क्या था! समझ गए गोस्वामी तुलसीदासजी महाराज प्रभुके आगमनको और पहचान गए हुलसीहर्षवर्धन प्रभु अपने परमाराध्य परमप्रिय परमपुरुष परमसुन्दर नीलजलधरश्याम लक्ष्मणाभिराम भगवान् श्रीरामजी को। गोस्वामीजीने विनय­पत्रिकाके उत्तरार्धमें इस घटनाका स्पष्ट संकेत करते हुए कृतज्ञता­ज्ञापन किया

तुलसी तोकौ कृपाल जो कियौ कोसलपाल।
चित्रकूट के चरित चेत चित करि सो।
(वि.प. २६४.५)

अब तो प्रभु श्रीरामजीने ही इस जङ्गमतुलसीकी सुगन्धिको दिग्दिगन्तमें बिखेरनेका निर्णय ले लिया और उनकी प्रेरणासे भगवान् भूतभावन शङ्करजीने चैत्रशुक्ल सप्तमी विक्रम संवत् १६३१की रातमें स्वप्नमें ही श्रीतुलसीदासजी महाराजको लोकभाषामें श्रीरामगाथा लिखनेकी प्रेरणा दी, जिसका उल्लेख करते हुए गोस्वामीजी स्वयं कहते हैं –

सपनेहुँ साँचेहु मोहि पर जौ हरगौरि पसाउ।
तौ फुर होउ जो कहेउँ सब भाषा भनिति प्रभाउ॥
(मा. १.१५)

काशीमें भगवान्‌ श्रीशङ्करजीका आदेश पाकर तुलसीदासजी महाराज श्रीअवध पधारे और चैत्रमासकी रामनवमीके मध्याह्न­वर्ती अभिजित् मुहूर्तमें गोस्वामी श्रीतुलसीदासजीके हृदयाकाशमें श्रीरामचरितमानसका प्रकाश हुआ-

संबत सोरह सै एकतीसा। करउँ कथा हरि पद धरि सीसा॥
नौमी भौम बार मधुमासा। अवधपुरी यह चरित प्रकासा॥
(मा. १.३४.४५)

श्रीअवध, श्रीकाशी तथा श्रीचित्रकूटमें निवास करके महाकवि गोस्वामी श्रीतुलसीदासजीने सप्त­प्रबन्धात्मक इस महाकाव्य श्रीरामचरितमानसजीकी रचना संपन्न कर ली। हुलसीनन्दन श्रीवाल्मीकि­नवावतार गोस्वामी श्रीतुलसीदासजी महाराजकी सहज­समाधि­लब्ध महादेवभाषाने अपनी लोकप्रियतासे संपूर्ण विश्वकी मानवजातिको मन्त्रमुग्ध कर लिया और एक ही साथ महर्षियोंकी तपस्या, आचार्योंकी वरिवस्या तथा कविवर्योंकी नमस्या रूप त्रिवेणीसे मण्डित होकर यह मानस­प्रयाग सारस्वतोंके लिये जङ्गम तीर्थराज बन गया। श्रीरामचरितमानसजीकी इतनी ख्याति बढ़ी कि जिससे खल स्वभाववाले मानी पण्डितोंको अकारण ईर्ष्या होनी स्वाभाविक थी और उन्होंने श्रीकाशीमें इस प्रकारका बवंडर भी खड़ा किया कि तुलसीदासने ग्राम्य भाषामें श्रीरामकथा लिखकर देवभाषा संस्कृतका अपमान किया है, परन्तु सत्य तो सत्य ही रहता है और वैसा ही हुआ। इस यथार्थकी परीक्षाके लिये श्रीकाशीके भगवान्‌ श्रीविश्वनाथजीके मन्दिरमें सभी ग्रन्थोंके नीचे श्रीरामचरितमानसजीकी पोथी रख दी गई और पट बंद कर दिया गया। जब दूसरे दिन प्रातःकाल पट खुला तब श्रीरामचरितमानसजीकी पोथी सभी ग्रन्थोंके ऊपर दिखाई दी जिसके मुख्य पृष्ठपर सत्यं शिवं सुन्दरम् लिखकर भगवान्‌ श्रीविश्वनाथजीने स्वयं अपने हस्ताक्षर कर दिये थे। इस दृश्यने भगवद्विमुख विद्याभिमानियोंके मुख काले किये एवं सभीने एक मतसे यह तथ्य स्वीकार किया कि यदि संस्कृत भाषा देवभाषा है तो श्रीगोस्वामि­तुलसीदासकृत श्रीरामचरितमानसजीकी भाषा महादेवभाषा है, क्योंकि संस्कृतमें उद्भट विद्वान् होकर भी गोस्वामी श्रीतुलसीदासजीने महादेवजीकी आज्ञासे श्रीरामचरितमानसजीको लोकभाषामें लिखा। जब श्रीरामचरितमानसजीको काशीके तत्कालीन मूर्धन्य विद्वान् अद्वैतसिद्धिकार श्रीमधुसूदन सरस्वतीने देखा तो वे आश्चर्यचकित रह गए और उन्होंने मानस और मानसकारकी प्रशस्तिमें एक बड़ा ही अद्भुत श्लोक लिखा

आनन्दकानने कश्चिज्जङ्गमस्तुलसीतरुः।
कविता मञ्जरी यस्य रामभ्रमरभूषिता॥

अर्थात् इस आनन्दवन श्रीकाशीमें श्रीगोस्वामी तुलसीदासजी एक अपूर्व जङ्गम अर्थात् चलते-फिरते श्रीतुलसीवृक्ष ही हैं जिनकी कविता रूपी मञ्जरीपर निरन्तर श्रीरामजी भ्रमर बनकर मँडराते रहते हैं, इसलिये उनकी कविता रूपी मञ्जरी सर्वदैव श्रीराम रूप भ्रमरसे समलङ्कृत रहती है।

तात्पर्य यह है कि जैसे श्रीतुलसीमञ्जरीको भ्रमर नहीं छोड़ता, उसी प्रकार श्रीतुलसीदासजीकी कविताको भगवान्‌ श्रीरामजी भी कभी नहीं छोड़ते, उनका इससे स्वाद्य-स्वादक-भाव संबन्ध है।

श्रीरामचरितमानसजीके संबन्धमें एक चमत्कारिक ऐतिह्य (घटना) प्रसिद्ध है। गोस्वामीजी जिन दिनों श्रीकाशीमें विराजते थे और तत्कालीन श्रीकाशी­नरेशपर उनकी कृपा भी थी, उसी समय एक विचित्र घटना घटी। श्रीकाशी­नरेशकी द्रविड़­नरेशसे परम मित्रता थी और इन दोनोंमें एक ऐसी सन्धि हो गई थी कि वे अपनी होनेवाली विषमलिङ्गी सन्ततियोंमें वैवाहिक संबन्ध करेंगे अर्थात् यदि द्रविड़­नरेशके यहाँ प्रथम पुत्र आता है तो उसका श्रीकाशी­नरेशकी प्रथम होनेवाली पुत्रीसे संबन्ध होगा। यदि इसके विपरीत श्रीकाशी­नरेशको प्रथम पुत्र उत्पन्न होगा तो वह द्रविड़ नरेशकी प्रथम होने वाली पुत्रीका पति बनेगा। परन्तु संयोगसे दोनों नरेशोंके यहाँ प्रथम बार पुत्रियोंका ही जन्म हुआ, किन्तु काशी­नरेशने असत्यका अवलम्ब लेकर अपनी पुत्रीको पुत्रके रूपमें ही प्रस्तुत किया। फलतः दोनोंकी सन्धिके अनुसार श्रीकाशी­नरेशके पुत्रके साथ (जो वास्तवमें पुत्री थी), द्रविड़­राजपुत्रीका विवाह निश्चित हो गया। गुप्तचरोंसे वास्तविकताका समाचार मिलनेपर द्रविड़­नरेशने अत्यन्त क्रुद्ध होकर श्रीकाशी­नरेशपर आक्रमण करनेका निश्चय कर लिया, अनन्तर श्रीकाशी­नरेश भयभीत होकर गोस्वामी श्रीतुलसीदासजीकी शरणमें आए तब गोस्वामीजी ने,

मन्त्र महा मनि बिषय ब्याल के। मेटत कठिन कुअंक भाल के॥
(मा. १.३२.९)

इस पङ्क्तिसे श्रीमानसजीके प्रत्येक दोहेको संपुटित करके श्रीरामचरितमानसजीका नवाहपारायण कराया और हो गया चमत्कार! श्रीकाशी­नरेशकी पुत्री पुत्ररूपमें परिणत हो गई। फिर उसका द्रविड़­राजपुत्रीके साथ महोत्सवपूर्वक विवाह संपन्न हुआ। इस ऐतिहासिक सत्य घटनासे श्रीमानसजीके प्रति लोगोंकी आस्था जगी, अद्यावधि जग रही है और भविष्यमें भी जगती रहेगी।

गोस्वामी श्रीतुलसीदासजीके जीवनका प्रत्येक क्षण श्रीसीता­रामजीके श्रीचरणारविन्दोंसे जुड़ा रहा और उनका मनोमिलिन्द उसी परमप्रेम­पीयूष­मकरन्दको पी-पीकर सतत मत्त होता रहा। इस प्रकार १२६ वर्ष पर्यन्त वैदिक साहित्योद्यानका यह मनोहर माली संवत् सोलह सौ अस्सी श्रावण शुक्ल तृतीया शनिवारको वाराणसीके असी घाटपर अन्तिम बार बोला –

रामचन्द्र गुन बरनि के भयो चहत अब मौन।
तुलसी के मुख दीजिए बेगहि तुलसी सौन॥

भावुक भक्तोंने जब बाबाजीके लम्बे आध्यात्मिक जीवनके अनुभव­सार­सर्वस्वके परिप्रेक्ष्यमें अपनी इति­कर्तव्यताकी जिज्ञासा की तब श्रीचित्रकूटी बाबा गोस्वामी श्रीतुलसीदासजी बोले –

अलप अवधि तामें जीव बहु सोच पोच
करिबे को बहुत है कहा कहा कीजिए।
ग्रन्थन को अन्त नाहिं काव्य की कला अनन्त
राग है रसीलो रस कहाँ कहाँ पीजिए।
बेदन को पार न पुरानन को भेद बहु
बानी है अनेक चित कहाँ कहाँ दीजिए।
लाखन में एक बात तुलसी बताए जात
जन्म जो सुधारा चाहो रामनाम लीजिए।

बस मौन हो गया श्रीरामकथाका अन्तिम उद्गाता–
संबत सोरह सै असी असी गंगके तीर।
श्रावण शुक्ला तीज शनि तुलसी तज्यौ शरीर॥

वस्तुतः हुलसीहर्षवर्धन कलिपावनावतार श्रीरामकथाके अनुपम एवं अन्तिम उद्गाता, सांस्कृतिक क्रान्तिके सफल पुरोधा, कविकुलपरमगुरु, अभिनव­वाल्मीकि गोस्वामी श्रीतुलसीदासजीके जीवनवृत्तका वर्णन मुझ जैसे जीवके लिये उतना ही दुष्कर है जितना सामान्य पिपीलिका के लिये निरवधि महासागरकी थाह लगाना। मैंने गोस्वामीजीकी ही कृपासे अपने अन्तःकरणमें भासित उन पूज्यचरणोंकी जीवनकथा जाह्नवीमें मात्र अपनी वाणीको ही स्नान करानेका प्रयास किया है।

लेख संपूर्ण हुआ, बस आप सब से इतना ही मेरा निवेदन है कि रोज कम से कम पांच दोहे श्रीमद् रामचरितमानस के पढ़ें और इसके एक एक अक्षर पर पूर्ण विश्वास रखें क्योंकि एक एक अक्षर इसका भगवान शिव के द्वारा कहा गया है।

अवध दुलारे अवध दुलारी सरकार की जय❤️

आनंद भाष्यकार आचार्य चक्रवर्ती यतीराज श्रीमद् जगद्गुरु रामानंदाचार्य भगवान की जय

भक्तमाल सुमेरू हिंदू धर्म रक्षक श्रीमद् गोस्वामी तुलसीदास जी महाराज की जय

Comment: Please post in English and read the guidelines for answering.